# Replacing everything between two $ signs to text between \( and \)

Tags: vim

I would like text placed between $ signs to be replaced with text be placed between "\(" and "\)" like in

```
replace $this text$
```

by

```
replace \(this text\)
```

I already tried the command "  %s/\$\(.*\)\$/\(\1\)/ " with the result that

```
replace $this text$ and $this also$.
```

is replaced by

```
replace \(this text$ and $this also\).
```

How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think you want:

```
:%s/\$\([^\$]*\)\$/\\(\1\\)/g
```

Explanation:

- You need to escape the `\` in the replacement string
- You need `[^\$]*` rather than `.*` in the search string, i.e. a sequence of 0 or more characters that are "not the dollar sign".

The will replace this text:

```
replace $this text$
replace $this text$ and $this also$.
```

With this text:

```
replace \(this text\)
replace \(this text\) and \(this also\).
```

Comment: This perfectly anwsers my question, thanks. But what should I do when I have a $ sign in the replacement string ?

Comment: As I understand it, you can't have a dollar sign in the replacement string, because the dollar sign is the delimiter.

Comment: I meant if it was escaped as in \$

Comment: That's quite a bit harder but it probably involves "negative lookbehind" and both capturing and non capturing groups. Perhaps you could ask a new question and supply your expected before and after text?